# Git submodules update after devcontainer starts

Tags: git, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm trying to create a devcontainer that automatically initializes and updates the submodules when the repository is first cloned.

I have a repository on GitLab with different submodules and a `devcontainer.json` file:

```
.
├── submodule1
├── submodule2
├── submodule3
└── .devcontainer
    ├── devcontainer.json
    └── modules.sh
```

Content of `devcontainer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:jammy",
    "postCreateCommand": "while [ -z \"$(ls ~/.vscode-server/extensions | grep gitlab)\" ] ; do sleep 1 ; done && sh ${containerWorkspaceFolder}/.devcontainer/modules.sh",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "gitlab.gitlab-workflow"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Content of `modules.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Usually, I use the VSCode [GitLab Workflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow) extension because it allows me to avoid in typing the credentials every time I want to commit something.

When I start the container, the `postCreateCommand` asks for credentials and blocks for input, while if I launch the `git submodule init` and `update` commands by hand after the container is launched, it works.

How can I get all the environment autometically configured without requiring git to ask for credential?